# diasble css style for specific element?

Tags: html, css

How can I set the default style for a checkbox in jquery or javascript or even html code?
or in another way how to disable the styling for  checkbox.

there is a external css file that set the style for all checkboxes, but I would like to override the style to default style for specific checkboxes.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done easiest by controlling the CSS that's styling your check box to begin with.

Instead of the CSS on your page laying styles for all constants (body img input). Instead assign classes to the individual items if you want them styled a special way.

So dont use:

```
input { background: #000; }
```

Use:

```
<style>
.mystyle { background: #000; }
</stlye>
</head>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" class="mystyle">
```

Check to make sure all CSS on your site is clear of constants, this will make sure everything is set to default on all your pages and only styled at your choosing.

Comment: I was thinking that the external css was untouchable. So if that's true, simply adding a class (like you said) to the input and styling that class would override the styles that are set on the element.  Class and ID styles have higher priority than element styles.

Answer (score 1):

I use css' `!important` whenever I want to override some values.

But most modern browsers allow specific css selector like

```
 input[type="checkbox"] { 
            //insert style here
  }
```

you can use this to manipulate any style specific to checkboxes.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery to reset a css value ... like

```
$(this).css("color","red");
```

------------samples------------

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

 /* see if anything is previously checked and reflect that in the view*/
 $(".checklist input:checked").parent().addClass("selected");

 /* handle the user selections */
 $(".checklist .checkbox-select").click(
 function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
 $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").attr("checked","checked");

 }
 );

 $(".checklist .checkbox-deselect").click(
 function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent().removeClass("selected");
 $(this).parent().find(":checkbox").removeAttr("checked");

 }
 );

 });
 });
```